# Trouble shooting reading CSV File code

Tags: c++, csv

I've been trying to trouble shoot this code for a couple of days now with no luck. I'm trying to read a CSV file (separated by a comma) that looks like this. I want to output the 100 spot (second row second column).

```
apple,party11,
0,0.1,
0.1,**100**,
//-Line 4 is empty-
```

My Code :

```
void Info() {
    Input1 = CSVfile("File1.csv");
    Input2 = CSVfile("File2.csv");
}

double CSVfile(string cvsfilein) {
    ifstream file;
    file.open(cvsfilein);
    if (file.fail()) {
        printf("----------Error no CSV File----------------");
        return 0;
    }
    vector<vector<string>> csvfile;
    double needvalue;
    while (file) {
        string filevalue1;
        if (!getline(file, filevalue1)) {
            cout << "failed heree1  " << endl;
            return -2;
            break;
        }
        ** // Never get past here**
            cout
            << "filevalue1  " << filevalue1 << endl;
        istringstream iss(filevalue1);
        vector<string> record;

        while (iss) {
            string filevalue2;
            if (!getline(iss, filevalue2, ',')) {
                if (filevalue2.empty())
                    continue;
                cout << "failed heree2  " << endl;
                return -2;
                break;
            }
            record.push_back(filevalue2);
            cout << "filevalue2  " << filevalue2 << endl;
        }

        csvfile.push_back(record);
        needvalue = atof(record[3].c_str()); // Converts the string to number
        cout << needvalue << endl; // just to check
        return needvalue;
        file.close();
    }
}
```

I never seem to get passed the first if `(!getline(file, filevalue1))`. I've tried using if `(filevalue1.empty()) continue;` and it doesn't seem to continue the code.. just stops it.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the [About] page soon. If your compiler isn't warning you about unreachable code, you aren't using enough warnings with your compiler.  You have: `return needvalue; file.close();` but the `file.close();` cannot be executed.  What other compiler warnings are you getting and ignoring?  However, either or both of those statements would account for not seeing a second line of input — the first because you exit the loop before reading a second line, and the second because you close the file and then check that it is still open.

Comment: All `break` are unreachable code too. Please compile with all warnigns (-Wall if GCC or Level 4 min if VS).

Comment: It is best if you can provide an MCVE ([How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)) or
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) — two names (and links) for the same basic idea.

Comment: Hey Jonathan, thanks! i moved the file.close() which released the first block.... now im getting failure in the while(iss) block [outputting failed heree2]

Comment: In your defense, given the right headers (`<cstdlib>`, `<fstream>`, `<iostream>`, `<sstream>`, `<string>` and `<vector>`), a `using namespace std;`, and declarations for the functions and `Input1` and `Input2` (and fixing up the botched comment line), the code compiles under GCC 4.9.1 on Mac OS X 10.9.4 with command line `g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c csv.cpp` and generates no warnings — which surprises me.

Comment: Yes im using all the right headers and namespace std. and ya i declar the function. Im using Visual studio express 2013 win32 (i guess thats how u could put it.) no clue what u mean by g++ -O3 -g -std=c++11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror -c csv.cpp lol But ya still getting the second error with no return of the 100 i want.

Comment: My understanding is getline reads from standard input, you probably want to use fscanf.  In any case, check that your arguments match the public description.

Comment: Have you printed the input line?  Does it contain what you think it contains?  Your question mentions `partvalue.empty()` but the code has no variable `partvalue`.  When I add a minimal `int main() { Info(); return 0; }` to the code, it crashes on the empty line at the end of the file.  And that's in `atof()` and probably because of the `record[3].c_str()` returning a null pointer.

Comment: @NerfHerder: `getline()` reads from the file stream given as its first argument, doesn't it?

Comment: Ya i changed it... had to spoof the code because of stuff. The if (filevalue.empty()) { continue; } didnt work. 


if (!getline(iss, filevalue, ','))
{
if (filevalue.empty()) { continue; }
cout << "failed heree2  " << endl;  return -2; break;
     }

Comment: What output are you getting?

Comment: Don't post code or any important updates in comments. Edit the question and put them there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary issue is the placement of `file.close()`, and secondary issues relate to various bits of unreachable code.  This mildly modified version of your code seems to work, even managing not to crash on the empty line at the end of the file(s) — I used two identical data files.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

double CSVfile(string cvsfilein);
void Info();

double Input1;
double Input2;

void Info() {
    Input1 = CSVfile("File1.csv");
    Input2 = CSVfile("File2.csv");
}

double CSVfile(string cvsfilein) {
    ifstream file;
    file.open(cvsfilein);
    if (file.fail()) {
        cerr << "----------Error no CSV File----------------\n";
        return 0;
    }
    vector<vector<string>> csvfile;
    while (file) {
        string filevalue1;
        if (!getline(file, filevalue1)) {
            cerr << "failed heree1  " << endl;
            return -2;
            break;
        }
        cout << "filevalue1  " << filevalue1 << endl;
        istringstream iss(filevalue1);
        vector<string> record;

        while (iss) {
            string filevalue2;
            if (!getline(iss, filevalue2, ',')) {
                if (filevalue2.empty())
                    continue;
                cerr << "failed heree2  " << endl;
                return -2;
            }
            record.push_back(filevalue2);
            cout << "filevalue2  " << filevalue2 << endl;
        }

        csvfile.push_back(record);
        //double needvalue = atof(record[3].c_str()); // Converts the string to number
        //cout << needvalue << endl; // just to check
        //return needvalue;
        //file.close();
    }
    file.close();
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    Info();
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output:

```
filevalue1  apple,party11,
filevalue2  apple
filevalue2  party11
filevalue1  0,0.1,
filevalue2  0
filevalue2  0.1
filevalue1  0.1,100,
filevalue2  0.1
filevalue2  100
filevalue1  
failed heree1  
filevalue1  apple,party11,
filevalue2  apple
filevalue2  party11
filevalue1  0,0.1,
filevalue2  0
filevalue2  0.1
filevalue1  0.1,100,
filevalue2  0.1
filevalue2  100
filevalue1  
failed heree1
```

The `needvalue` computation crashes the program on the empty line (dereferencing a null pointer in `strtod()` called from within `atof()`).  That's because there isn't a `record[3]` entry to convert to a string — not unreasonable.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me too (exactly until the conversion from string to double).

Firts of all getline returns an istream& so don't put it inside an if.

Now, If the "failed heree1" error isn't printed at all use try & catch.
Moreover, check the error bits:

```
try {
    getline(file, filevalue1);
} catch(ifstream::failure e) {
    cerr << "Exception happened: " << e.what() << endl
        << "Error bits are: "
        << "\nfailbit: " << file.fail() 
        << "\neofbit: " << file.eof()
        << "\nbadbit: " << file.bad() << endl;    
}
```

eofbit - The end of the source of characters is reached during its operations.
failbit - The input obtained could not be interpreted as a valid textual representation of an object of this type. Notice that some eofbit cases will also set failbit.
badbit - An error other than the above happened.

it failbit is on i would put my money on the csv-file's encoding.

source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/